# Error in 1:maxResults : argument of length 0 in gdscrapeR

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-mining

I am using `gdscrapeR` to extract Glassdoor Reviews. But, I cannot get past the very first code in `gdscrapeR`:

```
library(gdscrapeR)

df <- get_reviews(companyNum = "E40371")

Number of web pages to scrape: 
StartingError in 1:maxResults : argument of length 0
```

I went to the [creator's blog here](https://mguideng.github.io/2019-02-27-scrape-glassdoor-gdscrapeR/). The blog shows a breakdown of the `get_reviews` function. I think the problem is occurring here:

```
totalReviews <- read_html(paste(baseurl, companyNum, sort, sep = "")) %>%
  html_nodes(".tightVert.floatLt strong, .margRtSm.minor") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  sub("Found | reviews", "", .) %>%
  sub(",", "", .) %>%
  as.integer()

maxResults <- as.integer(ceiling(totalReviews/10))    #10 reviews per page, round up to whole number
```

I don't know what I have to do to fix this issue. I just want to extract Glassdoor Reviews. Please help!

Comment: There are a few issues here. It looks like GD changed their html format since the package was developed. First `get_maxResults` no longer works as you point out. But the specific error you're seeing comes from the `get_selectors_A` function which is defined in the body of `get_results`.  That function attempts to scrape a few different nodes from the website that no longer work. Lastly, the error handling in the `get_reviews` function is not not properly catching this error and returning an informative message.

Comment: Getting this package to work for you will require a number of updates. If you look at the github, there's only 1 contributor and they haven't commited any code for over a year. I'd recommend learning the basics of web scraping on your own and then attempting to write your own functions.